# Tableau Calculation on rows in same table

Tags: tableau-api

Tableau noob here and I am stuck on an what seems like a simple thing to achieve. The dumbed down version of my problem is this. I have a table imported in Tableau like below.

Code           Table            Value

FCT52          T1               10

FCT52          T2               20

FCT52          T3               40

What I am after is calculated field which will take value for T1 and multiply that with value for T2. 
Any pointers to how to go about doing thus will be very much appreciated.

thanks in advance
sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Tableau's `LOOKUP()` function. The below links explain pretty well.

http://breaking-bi.blogspot.com/2013/04/using-lookup-function-in-tableau.html

http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/en-us/help.htm#functions_functions_tablecalculation.html

Comment: thanks coge.soft..put me in the right direction. That first link was specially helpful.